# Creation and annihilation operators as operator-valued distributions

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In QFT, one usually talks about operator-valued distributions. But let's take, for instance, $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ and its associated Fock space $\mathcal{F} = \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3n})$. Creation and annihilation operators, respectivelly denoted by $a^{*}(h)$ and $a(h)$, $h \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ are treated as operator-valued distributions on $\mathcal{F}$ as follows. First, one restricts $a^{*}(h)$ and $a(h)$ to a dense subspace $\mathcal{D}_{\mathscr{S}}$, given by:
$$\mathcal{D}_{\mathscr{S}}:= \{\psi \in D_{0}: \psi_{n} \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{3n}), \forall n\}$$
with $D_{0}=\{\psi \in \mathcal{F}: \mbox{$\exists N$ such that $\psi_{n} = 0$ if $n\ge N$}\}$ and, since $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{3}) \subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$, one thinks of $a^{*}(h)$ and $a(h)$ as functions $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{3}) \ni h \mapsto a^{\#}(h)$. However, a distribution is characterized as being a *linear* map and $a(h)$ is an anti-linear in $h$. We could, however, define $h \mapsto a(h^{*})$, where $h^{*}$ is the complex conjugate of $h$, but this seems to mess up all results about $a(h)$, since the theory is described in terms of $a(h)$ instead of $a(h^{*})$. So, what is the problem here? Shouldn't an operator-valued distribution be linear? Is the use of the term "operator-valued distribution" conceptually misleading when considering $a(h)$ and we should treat this operator-valued function as an anti-linear map? Or should we, in fact, consider $a(h^{*})$ instead of $a(h)$ in this context? It doesn't seem what physicists do, however.

**ADD:** As discussed in the comments, if $a(h)$ is anti-linear in $h$, there's nothing wrong on defining $X(h) := a(h^{*})$. But let me stress two poits which seems to be troublesome:

*(1)* Because the Fock space is $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3n})$, the application of $a(h)$ to an element $\psi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3n})$ should lead to:
\begin{eqnarray}
(a(h)\psi)_{n} \equiv (a(h)\psi)(x_{1},...,x_{n-1}) = \sqrt{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\overline{h(x)}\psi(x,x_{1},...,x_{n-1})dx \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}

*(2)* To turn the theory into a field theory, one usually write:
\begin{eqnarray}
a(h) = \int \overline{h(x)}a(x)dx \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Here, $a(x)$ is formally treated as $a(\delta_{x})$, an operator on $\mathcal{F}$.

For clarity, these two topics were based on [Sigal & Gustafson](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642218651). But here is the problem: on [Reed & Simon's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0125850026) book, the authors state that (\ref{2}) should be treated as an equality in terms of quadratic forms, i.e. (\ref{2}) holds in the sense of:
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \psi, a(h)\varphi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\overline{h(x)}\langle \psi, a(x)\varphi \rangle \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{eqnarray}
If, however, we introduce $X(h) = a(h^{*})$ and use it instead of $a(h)$, then:
$$X(h) = a(h^{*}) = \int \overline{h(x)}a(x)dx$$
is not consistent with (\ref{1}) anymore, since $\overline{h(x)}$ in (\ref{1}) becomes $h(x)$. Moral: it seems that $a(h)$ itself is treated as an operator-valued distribution, not $X(h)$, but $a(h)$ is not linear in $h$. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: You confusion seems primarily about the notation. But many authors use slight variations on these notations, so it's impossible to tell if there's any contradiction, since you don't cite the source that seems to have confused you. In any case, even if the author you are reading has introduced an anti-linear mapping for $a^*$, you are absolutely free to mentally introduce a new symbol $X$, obeying $X(h) := (a(h^*))^*$, so that $X$ is also linear when $a$ is. Then, while reading, you can mentally re-express $a^*$ (however it was defined) in terms of $X$ wherever necessary.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine thank you for your comment! First, I think you meant $a$ instead of $a^{*}$ right? Second, I don't cite any reference in my post because I was following a lot of them, but all of them seem to agree on this notations. About the definition of $X(h)$, I agree to you that this is possible, but it seems to have some troublesome consequences. I'll edit my post to elaborate a little more on this!

Comment: @IgorKhavkine now that I edited the post, I think I got your point. If $X(h) = a(h^{*})$ then I write $X(h^{*})= a(h)$ as (\ref{2}) and everything seems to be consistent again! In fact, it seems just a matter of notation!

Comment: I think you get the point. But just for the record, for your last displayed equation to be consistent, it should have $h(x)$ not $\overline{h(x)}$ on the right-hand side. If you really follow enough sources, you'll find that some people make $a(h)$ linear and others anti-linear. Pick your favorite convention, and mentally adjust when reading other presentations.

Comment: Yes! You are right! You made me realize that my last expression should be $X(h^{*}) = a(h)$ instead of $X(h)=a(h^{*})$. Moreover, this makes sense in the sense that, as $X(h^{*})$ is a distribution, it is usually written (formally) as the right hand side of this last expression! Thanks so much for helping me!